# iOS App Icon is not reflecting once i deploy it onto a simulator or a phone in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios-icons

So I've been going at this for about two days now, and i have not been able to get the icon reflect onto the simulator or a phone, tried everything over the internet, but nothing seems to work, i'm on Xamarin forms

checked info.plist and this what i have, which seems right

```
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
```

I'm not sure what else to do here, tried removing the icons and creating a new iconset and adding the icons again, which resulted in just my info.plist getting updated and nothing else, any help would be appreciated and this seems to be recurring issue for a lot of people due to different causes. 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Also try to remove the app from your phone or simulator. Sometimes it's a caching issue there.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis i do that everytime before deploying

Comment: check Contents.json within AppIcon.appiconset folder , also make sure each image matches the actual size required

Comment: @Morse i wont be able to add the image, if it was of a different size, contents.json seems to be fine, i mean it has all the names of the images

Comment: which IDE VS Mac or windows? did you check ipa file generated? you will get its location from build log

Comment: @Morse visual studio mac

Comment: Make sure the version of VS and Xcode are up to date .Delete the folder `bin` and `obj` in your iOS project, then clean and rebuild it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out some third party library was breaking the app icon, a bug was logged for it